# Text rendered to email views are failing tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, email, rspec

I'm trying to set up an email to notify me of errors that occur in my Rails app. I'm encountering a small error in my tests that are more or less an inability to properly state what I'm wanting. Let's just say my errors include the following two lines

```
2013-04-23 02:06:06 ERROR -- Errors for OUT6984-20130422-111427-1366647266.5769058.mp3:
2013-04-23 02:06:06 ERROR -- {:phone=>['is invalid']}
```

When I'm writing this to my email, I'm writing my expectation as follows:

```
it "contains the right content" do
  @email.should have_body_text("2013-04-23 02:04:56 ERROR -- Errors for OUT6984-20130422-101157-1366643517.5758441.mp3:")
  @email.should have_body_text("2013-04-23 02:04:56 ERROR -- {:phone=>['is invalid']}")
end
```

but my tests are failing due to...

```
expected the body to contain "2013-04-23 02:04:56 ERROR -- {:phone=>['is invalid']}" but was 
"<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'> </head> <body> <h1>Errors for 20130423</h1> <br> <p>2013-04-23 02:04:56 ERROR -- Errors for OUT6984-20130422-101157-1366643517.5758441.mp3: 2013-04-23 02:04:56 ERROR -- {:phone=&gt;['is invalid']} </p> </body> </html> "
```

Where the `>` char in the final hash is being replaced with `&gt;`. How can I fix this, or rewrite the test in such a way that it passes? The test is doing exactly what I want it to, as is the code. I just don't know how to tell it that this *is* what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your @email instance variable is defined as, but instead of

```
@email.should have_body_text
```

try using

```
mail.body.encoded.should match
```

and check the output.